# RemoveEventListener click vaadin

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin, event-listener

I have the following code:

```
label.getElement().addEventListener("click", e->{
            System.out.print("\nHello there\n");
        });
```

But my app will, at times, add a different click listener to the same label. In some other frameworks, like android (the vaadin button acts the same), adding a second listener would remove the old one. However, in this case it does not.

How would I go about removing the listener in this case. So I only have a single click listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `addEventListener` method returns a `DomListenerRegistration` instance that you can use later on to remove that specific listener (using the `remove()` method).

Vaadin doesn't offer any way of removing all listeners.

Comment: So basically. You would have to do this: Registration registration = textView.addClickListener(e-> System.out.print("Hello0")); registration.remove(); Weird, but thanks!